# correct path to use during import CSV file in MySql

Tags: mysql, csv, import, hosting, aruba

I've a great problem during the import of a CSV file in a table of my site db.
Using Filezilla, folders structure of my site is the following:
www.mysite.it/mysite/scripts. In this folder (scripts) there are both the csv file to import in db and the PHP script to execute the import.

CSV file (with permissions setted to 777) is tabella.csv and it's a file like this:

```
"2016-09-02", "100.01", "4005.09", "5000", "1.09", "120.09", "100.5", "200.77"
"2016-09-03", "150.01", "4205.09", "5600", "1.10", "150.09", "300.5", "300.77"
```

The PHP script it's the following:

```
<?php

    $csvFile = "../scripts/tabella.csv";

    $realPath = realpath($csvFile);

    $db = @mysql_connect('**.***.***.***', 'Sql******', '*******');
    @mysql_select_db('Sql******_*');

    $query = 'LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE \' '. $realPath .' \' INTO TABLE rame
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY \',\'
        LINES TERMINATED BY \'\r\n\' 
        IGNORE 1 LINES
        (
            giorno,
            lmedollton,
            changedolleuro,
            euroton,
            lmesterton,
            delnotiz,
            girm,
            sgm
        )';
    if(!mysql_query($query)){
        die(mysql_error());
    }

    mysql_close($db);

?>
```

The error is 'file not found'. I try to use absolute path, single file, relative path.. I try to delete 'LOCAL' from the query.. I written to Aruba Service thinking that was a permissions files problem but they told me to use 'LOCAL' in the query.. Into Aruba Panel Control, in PhpMyAdmin there isn't 'Privileges' item in the menu so I can't to set them.. Has someone some ideas to know my problem? File path? Permissions?

Comment: Have you verified that you can in fact access the CSV using value in `$realPath` from the location where you are doing `LOAD DATA`?

Comment: why on earth are you writing code for this? Why not just use the mysql console?

Comment: @tim can I check it? I only verified that from url www.mysite/mysite/scripts/tabella.csv I can download the file..

Comment: I can't check, but I think you need a path on actual filesystem, not a URL.

Comment: @e4c5 because I've to set a cron job to execute the import..

Comment: @Tim in the query I use a path not a URL..

Comment: why can't a cron jab execute a query direct?

Comment: it can. Some people have other chunks of code they want php cmd line for

Comment: You have hosting tagged. Remember that going back to root absolute path can be funky in hosting environments where the `/home/xxx` or equivalent can be a real morphed up user acct stub. So what you think is correct pathing is not real in that virtual world. Quite different than your dev server on premise. When in doubt, go to ssh and fool around

Answer (score 0):

After

```
$realPath = realpath($csvFile);
```

make a

```
var_dump($realPath)
```

and see what is the path that you have. Then try to understand if the file is loading correctly or not. If you have in the same folder (scripts) both the `php` and the `csv` then your path is wrong.

```
$csvFile = "../scripts/tabella.csv";
```

This says to php to read up a folder, reenter the scripts again and find the `csv`. The `var_dump` will tell you if it's correct or not.